# how to get the current active browser url in my iPhone application

Tags: ios

I want to do the same in my iPhone app as the code below:

[How to copy the current active browser URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111275/how-to-copy-the-current-active-browser-url)

Comment: I'm going to doubt that it's possible due to sandboxing restrictions.  The user would have to specifically allow this, and if it were possible to allow this, there would be an entry for the permission in the settings (like there is for other applications, like Twitter).

Comment: is any API for it.please see this link .it work in mac os but i want in ios .   http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/83184-system-processes-start-time.html

Comment: "I doubt that it's possible" means I don't think there's an API for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that's not possible on iOS.

Comment: you have any other idea for estimate in my iphone app that user is open any social media site like fb .

Comment: There is no way to do this. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Actually i want to calculate time usage of social media site like fb. so user can be use fb in safari app in iphone.

Comment: @borrrden you say it is bad think. no it is usefull for that person they want to know about themself. they can reduce usage according to your self.i think not bad .

Comment: Apple will never allow this kind of behavior for 2 reasons.  1) It is shady.  2) This kind of background behavior is not allowed, nor should it be (it will needlessly waste the user's battery).

Answer (score 0):

`NSAppleScript` is unavailable in iOS. Apple doesn't let other apps to get the current active browser URL as well as many other things.