# Get current URL from browser in macOS

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a way to get current URL from currently opened browser (Chrome, Firefox, or Safari) using Swift?

Comment: It might be possible to do it with AppleScript.

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6111592) approach, that uses AppleScript. But I couldn't convert it to Swift properly, yet. Especially this line 
    `NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:(unichar*)[data bytes] length:[data length] / sizeof(unichar)];`

Answer (score 5):

Swift solution using AppleScript

```
func getBrowserURL(_ appName: String) -> String? {
    guard let scriptText = getScriptText(appName) else { return nil }
    var error: NSDictionary?
    guard let script = NSAppleScript(source: scriptText) else { return nil }

    guard let outputString = script.executeAndReturnError(&error).stringValue else {
        if let error = error {
            Logger.error("Get Browser URL request failed with error: \(error.description)")
        }
        return nil
    }

    // clean url output - remove protocol & unnecessary "www."
    if let url = URL(string: outputString),
        var host = url.host {
        if host.hasPrefix("www.") {
            host = String(host.dropFirst(4))
        }
        let resultURL = "\(host)\(url.path)"
        return resultURL
    }

    return nil
}

func getScriptText(_ appName: String) -> String? {
    switch appName {
    case "Google Chrome":
        return "tell app \"Google Chrome\" to get the url of the active tab of window 1"
    case "Safari":
        return "tell application \"Safari\" to return URL of front document"
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use some [Apple Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163433/can-you-execute-an-applescript-script-from-a-swift-application) like this:

```
set myURL to "No browser active"
set nameOfActiveApp to (path to frontmost application as text)
if "Safari" is in nameOfActiveApp then
    tell application "Safari"
        set myURL to the URL of the current tab of the front window
    end tell
else if "Chrome" is in nameOfActiveApp then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        set myURL to the URL of the active tab of the front window
    end tell
end if

display dialog (myURL)
```

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that if I'm checking for Firefox that I would add and else if statement for "Firefox"?

Comment: This is really useful for me
I Would like to click on Google Chrome-> View-> Developer-> Allow JavaScript from AppleEvent check using Apple Script 
Can you please help me to do the same

Comment: No Firefox doesn't support this simple way of getting the URL of the tab

Comment: Stopped working on Chrome 103.0.5060.53, execution error: Google Chrome got an error: Can’t get window 1. (-1728)

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a Mac app, make sure the following two actions are performed for the above scripts to work.

1. You add the following entitlements in your **.entitlements** file:

[image]

2. You add the following property in your **info.plist** file:

[image]